# Gridview row with dropdownlist

Tags: c#, gridview

I am working on an asp .net project. I have a gridview and on rowdatabound i want to put a dropdownlist to every cell of the row. So i have the following method.

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
    ddl.DataSource = getImpacts();
    ddl.DataBind();
    if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.Header)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(ddl);

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the dropdouwnlist is added only at the last cell! and when i debug, the for loop passes from all the cells!. How is this possible ?

Comment: You must recreate dynamically created controls on every postback. Since `RowDataBound` is only fired when you `DataBind` the GridView, you should use `RowCreated` instead. But you should databind your `DropDownList` in `RowDataBound`:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to create an instance of drop down list for each column

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
           DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
           ddl.DataSource = getImpacts();
           ddl.DataBind();
           e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(ddl);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create controls in `Row_Created`, databind controls in `Row_DataBound`. Othwerwise you'll have a problem on postbacks when the grid is not databound again.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert in your loop for , and iterate for each cell

```
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
           DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
           ddl.DataSource = getImpacts();
           ddl.DataBind();

           e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(ddl);
        }
```